# Notifications should load answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Realised notifications have been implemented in the Android app, as I received one for an answer to my question. However, when I clicked on the notification (the app wasn't in the foreground), the app opened, but displayed the previous view I was on.

I had to open the menu, return to the feeds view, and search for the new activity. No in-app top-right notification was displayed either.

Would be less confusing and useful to have the answer loaded and perhaps scrolled-to-focus, when the Android notification is selected.

Comment: sorry, posted on wrong site. please migrate to meta.

Comment: When multiple responses are received on different questions, they are all listed in a single notification. Which should be opened? Should individual notifications be sent for each response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in an earlier update last week.